# Android Studio 1.1.0 + Robolectric 2.4 causes java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError

Tags: java, android, testing, android-studio, robolectric

I'm trying run Robolectric tests within my projects.

I'm using Andriod Studio 1.1.0 with unit testing support (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) and I'm doing everything similar to https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle project.

When I try to run tests from within Android Studio I'm getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.robolectric.annotation.Config.application()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:747)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3178)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:199)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Any idea about the reason?

**EDIT:**

I changed my test to use custom test runner class instead of RobolectricTestRunner and @Config annotation and now I'm getting:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Application`

which seems also to be the reason of above AnnotationFormatError.

**EDIT 2:**

I was able to find workaround, although still I don't know the exact reason of the problem. When I run

`gradlew clean test`

from command line, I don't get AnnotationFormatError and after that, tests can be run within AndroidStudio without problems. Also it does not matter if I use @Config or custom test runner class. Also after every "Clean Project" I have to run "gradlew clean test" to make it working.

Comment: post the setup method of your test case.

Comment: Can you share one of your test class sources?

Answer (score 0):

To less information but I guess ... Your Android project contains a library module which use appcompat. When this is correct it looks like the same issue at https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/issues/4

Short: Replace ActionBarActivity with a simple FragmentActivity or switch to Robolectric 3.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: here is vanniktech from Github (who created issue #4), I also got that weird `AnnotationFormatError` under some circumstances and was not able to fix it

Comment: @Niklas Try to run `gradlew clean test` from command line. Do you get `AnnotationFormatError` from command line too? If not, run then tests within Android Studio - do you still get `AnnotationFormatError`?

Comment: @nenick Yes, I have library project which uses `com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0` but I'm not using ActionBarActivity.

Comment: What do you use instead? Have you somewhere an example?

Comment: @nenick From support library I'm using Fragment, FragmentActivity and NotificationCompat.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that `compileSdkVersion`  in my gradle file was set to 21 and since Robolectric does not officially support 21 (they do with version 3 which is in beta right now) I changed it to 18 and it works now.

Comment: If you like, robolectric snaphsot version is good stable. I switched with a complex application to sdk 21 and from 2.4 to 3.0-SNAPSHOT and it works much better ;) But I would suggest to create your own more stable robolectric release and depend on that.